# When did the custom of using 2 people for hagbah and gelilah begin?

Tags: sources-mekorot, hagbah-gelilah

Megillah 32a says:

> עשרה שקראו בתורה הגולל ספר תורה קיבל שכר כולן
>
> If ten have read from the Torah (meaning that at least ten verses have been read; not that there was a minyan of at least 10 people or that there were 10 aliyot. See Rash"i, there), the one who rolls it up receives the
>   reward of all of them.

(Edited with thanks to DoubleAA & YehudaW providing me some historical context)

As there were no "poles" (*atzei chayim*) during the time of the Gemarah, it makes sens that one person did both lifting and rolling. This was called just *gollel*.

At what point and for what reason was what we now call *hagba* - "lifting" added? Was it added at the time that the poles were attached, and was it mainly for that reason? Related - when / why were the poles used? Even after their attachment, initially, did one person do both or were the jobs separated?

Comment: I think in sefardi shuls, they call the whole thing including the lifting gelilah

Comment: You are comparing terminology anachronistically.

Comment: Some communities have the custom that the person who raises the Torah Scroll (Hagbah) also rolls it closed (Gelila) before sitting down. - Then the second person ties it up and puts the mantle on.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'll cede that. Feel free to edit or suggest.

Comment: And to follow  up on @Daniel's comment,  Babylonia (Iraq) is Sfardi (Mizrachi).

Comment: Sefardim do Hagbah *before* reading, so according to them this statement can't be referring to that (or they would say practice changed, I don't know which).

Comment: DanF: @DoubleAA is correct; גלילה in the Talmud includes both גלילה and הגבהה (see [MB 147:5](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%96#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.90), see also [Rama OC 147:4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%96#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.93) and [*Magein Avraham* 147:11](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x523)).

Comment: The poles (eitzim) are post Talmudic. Originally a scroll was rolled on one's lap.

Comment: @YehudaW That's useful info - I didn't know this. If you can source this and, perhaps, locate a date, that may make an answer. Would you know why the poles were placed?

Comment: @YehudaW, on one's lap? http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16515/jewish/Chapter-8.htm#v=4

Comment: @YehudaW And the Yerushalmi knew of the eitzim http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_47657_56.pdf

Comment: @YehudaW That is not true. See Bavli Bava Batra 14a

Comment: @DanF  Megilla 32A, the Schottenstein edition, footnote 12 says, "... He places the scroll on his lap, one roll up against his body, and the other away from his body.  ... when he rolls it, he will be rolling abd pulling the outer roll to take up..."

Comment: @double-aa Perhaps the pole there (BB 14a) was just being used as a measure of the width of the first and last margin. Do you see a statement describing how the scroll is attached to the poles?

Comment: @YehudaW Perhaps? That doesn't seem to be the traditional understanding.

Comment: @double-aa  Do you see a description in the Talmud Bavli of how hagba is to be done (e.g., hold the Torah over your head with 3 columns visible)?

Comment: @YehudaW I don't recall one offhand, no.